# How to calculate daily total?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

i have this code and its working but i want it to return `dailyTotals` list with four values, at the moment it is being returned with three values ... i cant seem to figure out how to make it return `dailyTotals` with four values.  BTW the `billTotals` and `dateList` are of the same lengh which is currently 7 and they will grow. `billTotals` and `dateList` will always remain the same length

```
List<double> dailyTotals = new List<double>();

        string dateValue = "";
        double oneDayTotal = 0;
        int n = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < billTotals.Count; i += n)
        {
            dateValue = dateList[i];
            oneDayTotal = 0;

            while (dateValue == dateList[n])
            {
                oneDayTotal += billTotals[n];

                n++;
            }

            dailyTotals.Add(oneDayTotal);
        }

        return dailyTotals;
```

[EDIT]: Im sorry i should have written this before :/
in the database i have billTotals and the date for each bill stored. so, one date can have multiple bills associated with it. what im trying to do is grab one months data and sum the totals for each day. so the logic i used in the while loop is supposed to sum up the totals while the date is the same ... i hope this makes the scenario more clear. :)

Comment: did you try debugging the code and see what values are getting assigned to each var? Sometimes it's hard to tell from code but debugger will show you what's actually going on with code.

Comment: This code is in a dll file i cant seem to get the debugger there :/

Comment: I'm close to voting -1 for such a non-informative title. If you think about it, it could probably apply to almost all questions posted here.

Comment: Can you post the code where you read the data from the database?

Comment: Still waiting for the code.... why don't you post it? Did you solve the problem already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never reset n, so you are increasing i by increasingly large amount, skipping over some numbers.

You need to set `n = 0` inside the loop.

```
int n = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < billTotals.Count; i += n)
{
    dateValue = dateList[i];
    oneDayTotal = 0;

    n = 0;  // This counts the number of equal dates.
    while (i + n < dateList.Length && dateValue == dateList[i + n])
    {
        oneDayTotal += billTotals[i + n];
        n++;
    }

    dailyTotals.Add(oneDayTotal);
}

return dailyTotals;
```

You could also rewrite the code entirely to simplify it and avoid this curious way of incrementing your loop variable. I would suggest creating an array of objects that hold both the date and the total, then you can use LINQ to solve your problem without any complex loops:

```
var dailyTotals = datesAndTotals
    .GroupBy(x => x.Date)
    .Select(g => g.Sum(x => x.BillTotal))
    .ToList();
```

You can also use `Zip` instead of creating a separate class, though it will be more readable with the class.

Comment: i get an `index was out of range` exception :/

Comment: @Raiden: Yes there's a missing check. Fixed now, but as I said it's much better to completely throw away all that complex code and replace it with the simple expression at the end of my answer. It does the same thing but without all the complex loop logic.

Comment: The problem is that i'm not really good with linq so it didn't come to my mind + im having trouble understanding what's written :( can you explane

Comment: @Raiden: It group things with the same date `.GroupBy(x => x.Date)` , then sum the bill totals for each date `.Select(g => g.Sum(x => x.BillTotal))`. That's what you are trying to do, right? Using LINQ you can express what result you want instead of coding the algorithm for calculating it.

Comment: @Raiden: Another advantage is that the LINQ code can work directly on the database and give you the result directly without first having to fetch all rows from the database. No changes need to be made to the LINQ code to make it work against the database, apart from changing `datesAndTotals` to point at your data context instead of an in-memory object.

Comment: yes that is exactly what im trying to do :)

Comment: having a hard time implementing :/